# How to create this 3D gummibear font effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

When I have some font, how can I make it look more 3D, like for example the letters in the gelini logo?

I imagine one part is pumping them up and the other one to add shadows and highlights.

Could this be achieved with photoshop or do I need the letters in a 3D program with renderer?

Here is the logo I mean, nut it doesn't need to be the exact same effect, just more plastic:

[image: http://www.lizenzbranche.de/DBImages/brands/Gelini_Logo.jpg]

Comment: You can do this with layers, blending and effects in Photoshop. Try searching online for some Photoshop tutorials about it and play around with them to get that result. Maybe try keywords such as "photoshop tutorial 3d jelly effect."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using a combination of layer styles. It's by no means perfect but I was able to produce this in a few minutes by messing with one of the standard gel styles that comes with Photoshop:

[image]

There'll be a load of ways to create this but here are my layers:

[image]

It might help to get you going anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple font like [Univers font free](https://fontsio.com/univers-font-free/) that's been hand edited.

In my (very) rough version below I used that font, kerned it out to +115 and "created outlines" with shift+control+O

Then I used the Convert Anchor Point tool shift+C to round the corner.

Good luck!